# Reformulation of a Linear Complementarity Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I'm reading Peng Liu's [disseration](http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/706/1/pengliudiss.pdf#page=15) (page 15) to learn about the linear complementarity problem (LCP).

They describe the LCP as finding $v$ such that

$$ Av - f \geq 0 $$
$$ v \geq g $$
$$ (Av - f) \cdot (v -g) = 0$$

for a fixed matrix $A$ and vectors $v$, $f$. (The inequalities are component-wise, as usual)

They write that the problem is equivalent to

$$\min ( Av-f, v-g) = 0$$

which makes sense, and also to

$$\min ( v-A^{-1}f, v-g) = 0 $$

which I don't follow. I guess we're assuming that $A$ is invertible, probably positive definite.

What am I missing?

Comment: Positive definiteness does not help. You need that the entries of $A^{-1}$ are non-negative.

Comment: Thanks @daw, but that's certainly too specific for the author's applications

Comment: Thats not too specific. It is necessary in order that the transformation is true at all. It might be fulfilled in the application, though. $Av\ge0$ is equivalent to $v\ge0$ if and only if $A^{-1}$ is non-negative entry-wise.